# Primefaces commandButton inside a DataGrid

Tags: primefaces

I have a datagrid and its element is a panel and some components including a commandbutton, i load the data from the bean but the actionlistning of the commandbutton is not firing even in eclipse debug mode it does not reach the method.

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
    <p:layoutUnit header="Islands" position="west" closable="false" collapsed="false" collapsible="true" size="180">
        <h:form>
        <p:toolbar>
            <f:facet name="left"><p:commandButton value="New island" icon="ui-icon-disk"></p:commandButton></f:facet>
        </p:toolbar>
        <p:dataGrid columns="1" value="#{empcreator.islands}" var="island">
            <p:panel header="#{island.name}" style="text-align:center">
                <p:toolbar>
                    <f:facet name="left">
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-disk"></p:commandButton>
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash"></p:commandButton>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="right">
                        <p:commandButton value="Load" actionListener="#{empcreator.loadIsland}"></p:commandButton>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:toolbar>
                <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel value="ID"></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{island.id}"></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:outputLabel value="X"></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{island.x}"></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Y"></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{island.y}"></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Model"></p:outputLabel>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{island.model}"></p:outputLabel>                                                                             
                </p:panelGrid>  
            </p:panel>              
        </p:dataGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="center" collapsed="false" collapsible="false" id="mainl" >
        <div id="cmain" style="padding:0px" onresize="onWindowResize"></div>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

is the problem related to the form ?

Comment: Do you have bean validation in your fields `#{island.id}` etc. ? If validation fails then the methods are not being processed . Also try changing `actionListener` to `action`.

Comment: when i call the event from outside the Datagrid it works!

Answer (score 0):

It should be nested from p:column, it worked fine